# Relative Import: No Known Parent Package

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to do a relative import. From my understanding, I should have an `__init__.py` file to suggest this is a module.

Let's say I have:

```
$ ls
__init__.py foo.py bar.py
```

`__init__.py` is an empty file. Additionally:

```
$ cat foo.py
from .bar import MyExampleClass

thing = MyExampleClass()
```

and

```
$ cat bar.py
class MyExampleClass():
    pass
```

So, why do I get?

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Your directory which contains all this file will be considered as a package and now you can update code in foo.py:

```
from .bar import MyExampleClass
```

to

```
from bar import MyExampleClass
```

Other thing should work as expected

Comment: While this technically works, wouldn't that potentially conflict with other modules named `bar`? Or is the behaviour to *always* look in the local folder first?

Comment: Yes it causes issue when conflict with builtin modules which we can access directly like `import os` incase we created custom `os.py` file. If anyone have solution put in comments.